# When will the Gramercy be imploded?

Tags: events, las-vegas

The Last Vegas Sun [reports](http://www.lasvegassun.com/photos/galleries/2015/jan/23/the_gramercy_construction_/) that the never-finished residential building will be imploded on February 17, 2015, at 2am.

The [KTNV](http://www.jrn.com/ktnv/news/The-Gramercy-plans-to-implode-unfinished-9-story-tower-289500961.html) claims Feb 15, 8am. Is there a more authoritative source for this? Traveling to be there on Sunday morning is more feasible than on Tuesday morning.

Their [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/TheGramercyLV) and website are completely silent. I called and got an automated message advising to check the website.

Comment: Looks like you've got an [answer here](http://www.quora.com/Las-Vegas/When-exactly-will-The-Gramercy-be-imploded/answer/Tom-Bath?share=1), if you want to answer your own question for other readers :)

Comment: @Mark: posted my answer. How did you find my Quora question?

Comment: I was looking on twitter to see if there was a Vegas events account or something, and the guy who answered you had tweeted his answer :)

Comment: Whoever downvoted this question - why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to a long-time Las Vegas resident who answered the [same question on Quora](http://www.quora.com/Las-Vegas/When-exactly-will-The-Gramercy-be-imploded/answer/Tom-Bath?share=1), the implosion will happen on Sunday, Feb 15 at 8am. See you there!

**UPDATE** I watched the implosion live, quite the show. Here's an amazing 4k drone footage: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ppg-4HEJPSk